# Displaying fully qualified name of the function

Tags: c++, function

```
#include <iostream>
class A{
    public:
    void myfunction(){
        std::cout << __func__; 
    }
};
int main(){
    A obj;
    obj.myfunction();
}
```

Output is `myfunction`. Unfortunately `__funct__` does not work. How to output the fully qualified name of the member function i.e `A::myfunction` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no standard defined way for the same. However if you are using gcc you can use `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` instead of `__func__`.

Standard C++ (i.e C++03) does not have either `__func__` or `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`.

C++0x derives `__func__` from C99 and it is defined in 8.4.2/8 (n3290)

> The function-local predefined variable `__func__` is defined as if a definition of the form
>
> `static const char __func__[] = "function-name ";`
>
> had been provided, where function-name is an implementation-defined string

Comment: I believe `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` becomes standard in C++0x?

Comment: Ah, I see, so it was `__func__`.

Comment: Still, for some purposes, there remains the issue of stripping the return type at compile-time, which might be non-trivial (something around the lines of 'cut at the first space left of the first opened paraenthesis', but try doing _that_ at compile time)

Answer (score 3):

As @Prasoon says, there's no standard way.
For Visual Studio, `__FUNCTION__` displays the fully qualified name.

Comment: no standard, but Boost offers a cross-platform macro: BOOST_CURRENT_FUNCTION, see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/utility/current_function.html