# How to get a fully-qualified function name in C++ (gcc), _excluding_ the return type?

Tags: c++, gcc

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6151558/displaying-fully-qualified-name-of-the-function) describes how to use `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` to get a full name of a function, including its return type, argument types, namespace and template parameters.

Consider the following, beautiful function:

```
namespace foo {
namespace {

template<int i>
int (*bar(int (*arg)(int *)))(int *) {
    printf("%s\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

    return arg;
}

} // anonymous namespace
} // namespace foo
```

If it's not obvious to you, the function takes, and returns, a pointer to an `int *` -> `int` function.

Its pretty name is, when compiled with `g++` (4.9),

```
int (* foo::{anonymous}::bar(int (*)(int*)))(int*) [with int i = 1337]
```

and, with `clang++` (3.5),

```
int (*foo::(anonymous namespace)::bar(int (*)(int *)) [i = 1337])(int *)
```

Those strings are pretty unsuitable for testing whether the function is part of a certain namespace. Is there any other way, or, say, a compiler-provided library to parse those strings?

To clarify, I'd rather have something like

```
foo::{anonymous}::bar <I don't care about anything beyond this point>
```

Even more ideally, I'd like a compile-time way, such as a `constexpr` function `split(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__)` that yields some sort of list of

- fully qualified function name
- return type
- type of arg0
- type of arg1

etc, but I'd be happy with just the fully-qualified function name.

Comment: Sounds like you just want the `__FUNCTION__` macro?

Comment: `__FUNCTION__` will give me just `bar`, which is not enough. `__func__`, too.

Comment: So you want the namespace and the name, but not the return type nor parameters?  Why?

Comment: This is used in the logging subsystem of a project. I want to be able to set logging rules such as "don't log DBG messages from namespace foo or class C". Non-deterministic clutter in front of the actual fully qualified funtion name makes this impossible.

Comment: So you want to do something like `printf(%s\n", modify(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__));`, where `modify()` is just some string processing function?

Comment: Basically, yes, that would be an acceptable solution. Ideally, `modify()` would be `constexpr`.

Answer (score 5):

After a more careful observation I wrote this code:

```
template <typename InputIterator, typename T>
InputIterator findClosing( InputIterator first, InputIterator last, T close )
{
    if (first == last)
        return last;

    auto open = *first;
    unsigned counter = 1;
    while (++first != last)
    {
        if (*first == close && --counter == 0)
            return first;
        if (*first == open)
            ++counter;
    }

    return last;
}

template <std::size_t N,
          std::size_t N2>
std::string f(char const(&str)[N], char const(&name)[N2])
{
    using namespace std;

    // Argument to isalnum must be unsigned:
    auto cond = [] (unsigned char c) {return !isalnum(c) && c != '_';};

    auto iter = str;
    for (;;++iter)
    {
        iter = search( iter, end(str),
                       begin(name), end(name)-1 );

        if (iter == end(str))
            throw invalid_argument("");

        if ((iter == begin(str)      || cond(iter[-1]))
         && (iter ==   end(str) - N2 || (cond(iter[N2-1]) && iter[N2-1] != ':')))
            break;
    }

    auto origin_iter = iter;
    while(iter != begin(str))
    {
        --iter;
        for (auto p : {"()", "{}"})
        if (*iter == p[1])
            iter = findClosing(reverse_iterator<char const*>(iter+1),
                               reverse_iterator<char const*>(begin(str)),
                               p[0]).base()-2;

        if (cond(*iter) && *iter != ':')
            return string(iter+1, origin_iter+N2-1);
    }

    return string(iter, origin_iter+N2-1);
}
```

It should work with any function, assuming no unnecessary whitespace is existent in `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` and `__func__` contains solely the unqualified function name.

#### [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e1237fdf0bd06c1e).

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't do quite what you've asked in that it doesn't return a single value which is a `constexpr` string, but it gets close.  It is, however, fully `constexpr` and it returns a pointer to the beginning of the namespace, and a pointer to the end of it (the beginning of the function name), and, optionally the length of that string.

```
constexpr bool isNotIdentifierChar(const char *pf)
{
    return !isalnum(*pf) && *pf!='_';
}

constexpr const char* getNamespaceEnd(const char *pf, const char *func)
{
    return (isNotIdentifierChar(pf) && 0==strncmp(&pf[1], func, strlen(func))
    && isNotIdentifierChar(pf+strlen(func)+1) && ':'!=pf[strlen(func)+1])  
        ? &pf[1] 
        : getNamespaceEnd(++pf, func);
}

constexpr const char* getNamespaceStartIter(const char *pf, const char *end)
{
    return (*pf==' ' && strchr(&pf[1], ' ') > end) 
        ? &pf[1] 
        : getNamespaceStartIter(++pf, end);
}

constexpr const char* getNamespaceStart(const char *pf, const char *func)
{
    return getNamespaceStartIter(pf, getNamespaceEnd(pf, func));
}

constexpr size_t getNamespaceSize(const char *pf, const char *func)
{
    return getNamespaceEnd(pf, func) - getNamespaceStart(pf, func);
}
```

One can't have a `constexpr` return a `std::string` because the `std::string` (or any equivalent construct) has a non-trivial destructor, but we can return the start and end of the namespace like this:

```
printf("%s\n", std::string(
        getNamespaceStart(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __func__),
        getNamespaceEnd(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __func__)+strlen(__func__)
    ).data());
```

This version includes the function name ("bar" in this case), but it can also be omitted by simply leaving out the `+strlen(__func__)`.

We could also make it somewhat cleaner by using a simple class:

```
class NamespaceString {
public:
    NamespaceString(const char *pf, const char *func) 
        : start(getNamespaceStart(pf, func)),
          end(getNamespaceEnd(pf, func)) {}
    std::string getString() const {
        return std::string(start, end);
    }
private:
    const char *start;
    const char *end;
};
```

Then the use within the function is a bit cleaner:

```
static const NamespaceString ns(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __func__);
printf("%s\n", ns.getString().data());
```

Updated demo which includes both @Columbo's answer and this one: [live code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d0da607994c0c04a)

Comment: `strlen` and `str(n)cmp` are `constexpr`? interesting... I re-implemented them as `constexpr` just yesterday...

Comment: Both your and Columbo's approaches appear to be searching for a `__func__` substring in `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`, then searching backwards until you encounter the first space... isn't it comparably simple to construct an example where this fails, possibly horribly? e.g. `float mynamespace::f()`?

Comment: @mic_e Yes, my first approach was trivially wrong. However, the new code should cope with such functions.

Comment: @mic_e: Yes, my function can very easily be fooled into failing horribly - for one thing, it doesn't work with clang. Both answers fail with nested namespaces that are identical to the function name.

Comment: I've amended my answer to correctly deal with nested namespaces that are identical to the function name.

Comment: This doesn't work if you try to get the function name from a lambda block.

Comment: @CristianAdam: True.  For a function that gcc pretty prints like this: `auto bar::foo::(anonymous namespace)::(anonymous class)::operator()(int, int) const`, the function I proposed emits this: `class)::operator()` but at least it doesn't segfault like the other solution.  Either or both could be altered to address this particular case, but I lack the motivation to do so at the moment.