# Can I get the namespaces/function/classes hierarchy of an object instance? - c++

Tags: c++

I have an external `Parameter class` I need to define as global objects (instances) inside different namespaces. I insert a pointer to each instance of the class to a map.

*the problem*:

not all parameter names are unique and I need a unique name as key to each instance, can I get the namespace hierarchy of the object name as prefix for his name?

**RegisteredGlobalObject.cpp:**

```
RegisteredGlobalObject::RegisteredGlobalObject(const string& uid, int val) {
    m_mapUidToParamPair[uid] = val;
}
```

**ParamsDef.h:**

```
namespace base {
namespace vpeservice {

    extern RegisteredGlobalObject int_64_param;

} // namespace vpeservice
namespace otherservice {

    extern RegisteredGlobalObject int_64_param;

} // namespace otherservice
} // namespace base
```

**ParamsDef.cpp:**

```
namespace base {
namespace vpeservice {

    RegisteredGlobalObject int_64_param(getInstatnceDefenitionPlaceStr()+"int_64_param", 1);

}
namespace otherservice {

    RegisteredGlobalObject int_64_param(getInstatnceDefenitionPlaceStr()+"int_64_param", 2);

}
}
```

can I implement the function `getInstatnceDefenitionPlaceStr()` which returns "`base::vpeservice`" for the first call and "`base::otherservice`" for the second?

Comment: Seems not possible according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21776142/how-to-get-string-for-current-namespace-in-macro). I guess you have to manually prepend the namespace strings.

Comment: this question refer to compile time, I can get it in runtime if possible.

Comment: How about `__FILE__`/`__LINE__` for a unique string?

Comment: I need some better logic so I can get the key from .json file from other place. this is why I thought define the namespaces with the same hierarchy of the .json file.

Comment: Perhaps the string returned by typeid(myObj).name() would help?

Comment: I'll try, thanks. I thought using it only on template types

Comment: returns the same string for different namespaces

Comment: Please use `@username` when replying, otherwise we don't get notifications.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat will do

Comment: I don't know of a way to get the full name of an object. Some compilers support getting a full name of a function, in the form of `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` macro. You could arrange for the object to be defined within a function, e.g. `bool RegisterHelper() {static RegisteredGlobalObject int_64_param(ExtractNamepaceFromPrettyFunction(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__)+"int_64_param", 1); return true} bool register_helper = RegisterHelper();` This will be very much non-portable and compiler-dependent.

Comment: Can you generate the namespace (e.g. with a macro), then you know its name? Or is it fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this is my solution to this case.
hope it will help someone.

I defined a macro for **every internal** namespace that will define a function inside the namespace to get current `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` path.

then I used [How to get a fully-qualified function name in C++ (gcc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26871631/how-to-get-a-fully-qualified-function-name-in-c-gcc-excluding-the-return) with some modifications (you can see the `f(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,__func__)` call inside the macro:

```
#define PARAMETERS_SECTION(name) namespace name {\
std::string getPath()\
{\
    return f(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,__func__);\
}\
#define configureParam(type, name, val) RegisteredGlobalObject name(getPath()+#name, val);
```

then I changed **ParamsDef.cpp** to be:

```
namespace base {
PARAMETERS_SECTION(vpeservice) {

    configureParam(int64_t, int_64_param, 1)

}
PARAMETERS_SECTION(otherservice) {

    configureParam(int64_t, int_64_param, 2)

}
}
```

and got keyes:

> base::vpeservice::int_64_param

> base::otherservice::int_64_param